# Scikit-learn does not show progress after fit

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scikit-multilearn

I'm facing an issue with scikit-learn version 1.0.2:

```
model = OneVsRestClassifier(RandomForestClassifier())

parameters = {'estimator__n_estimators': [50, 100, 200],
              'estimator__criterion': ['gini', 'entropy'], 
              'estimator__max_depth': range(10, 25), 
              'estimator__min_samples_split': [2, 5, 8], 
              'estimator__max_features': ['sqrt'], 
              'estimator__min_samples_leaf': [1, 2, 5, 8],
              'estimator__class_weight': ['balanced']}

model_tunning = GridSearchCV(model, 
                             param_grid=parameters,
                             scoring='precision_micro',
                             n_jobs = 8, 
                             verbose = 10)

model_tunning.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

**For some reason no progress happening after significant amount of time**. In comparison with version 0.20.3 it shows more fits.
I also checked syntax with shift+tab in order to see if there is a difference.

I also updated numpy to 1.21.1 and mock to 4.0.3. I there any other versions of different packages needed?

Comment: I tried your code with the `iris` dataset and it seems to work fine - in `ipython` verbose progress messages started screaming out immediately and continuously.  Maybe there is something "off" about your current environment?  If you create a new `venv` and try again, does it work?

Comment: @rickhg12hs I tried with an ordinary classifier and iris dataset. It still shows amount of fits but I don't see any progress and its' status. Basically it's just shown post-factum when calculation is completed. Maybe there are changes in "verbose"? Because I do not understand how to display status

Comment: I used the most recent packages, except for perhaps `numpy` since I use `numba` (my `numpy` is only slightly behind though and probably irrelevant).  I don't  have `mock` and not sure if that's significant.  Are you using the most recent packages?  When I ran your code with the `iris` dataset, several status messages were printed per second and there were more than a thousand of them.  Eventually it completed normally and the results looked reasonable.  Did you try from a new `venv`? ... and from `ipython`?